# Выбор вложенных аргументов из DataSource для dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите определиться с концепцией.
Есть структура

```
 public partial class formMain : Form
    {
        List<datastruct> ds = new List<datastruct>();
    }


public class datalang
{
    public string en_EN { get; set; }
    public string ru_RU { get; set; }
}

public class datavalue
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public datalang value_lang { get; set; }
}
public class datastruct
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_long { get; set; }
    public datalang name_lang { get; set; }
    public string data_type { get; set; }
    public string cur_byte { get; set; }
    public string[] test { get; set; }
    public List<datavalue> value { get; set; }
}
```

ds заполняется из json, но для понимания примера заполню так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ds.Add(new datastruct() { name = "CFG1", name_long = "cgf1 long", data_type = "BINARY", cur_byte = "1", 
 test = new string[] { "en1", "ru1" }, name_lang = new datalang {en_EN = "en1", ru_RU = "ru1"},
                    value = new List<datavalue>()
                    { 
                     new datavalue {value = "val1", value_lang = new datalang {en_EN = "val_en1", ru_RU = "val_ru1" } },
                     new datavalue {value = "val2", value_lang = new datalang {en_EN = "val_en2", ru_RU = "val_ru2" } }
                    } });
            }
```

Надо вывести определённые куски на отображение\редактирование. Допустим выбрал отображение через DataGridView. И вот тут полное непонимание возможностей как это можно сделать, и можно вообще.
Надо отобразить три колонки.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

            var c_name = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                HeaderText = "name short",
                Width = 50,
                DataPropertyName = "name",
                Name = "name"
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(c_name);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        }
```

Первая колонка отобразилась, но можно ли таким способом отобразить данные для второй колонки, если надо вывести значения конкретного языка, например ds.name_lang.ru_RU ? данные при этом должны редактироваться и сохранятся в первоисточнике.
Если можно, то третья колонка для меня ещё сложней - должна содержать список ComboBox из значений конкретного языка, например ds.value.value_lang.ru_RU. кроме того мне надо оперировать текущим выбором ComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совет: пишите имена классов с большой буквы.

Вы неверно интерпретировали структуру данных. Здесь должен быть словарь, так как язык определяется в рантайме, а не при компиляции. Да и каждый раз переписывать код для поддержки нужного языка было бы неудобно.

У меня бы получилось как-то так.

```cs
public class DataValue
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> value_lang { get; set; }
}
public class DataStruct
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_long { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> name_lang { get; set; }
    public string data_type { get; set; }
    public string cur_byte { get; set; }
    public string[] test { get; set; }
    public List<DataValue> value { get; set; }
}
```

Десериализуется оно правильно. Тогда вы можете добавить в структуру еще одно свойство, которое будет доставать текст на нужном языке.

```
private string _lang = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name; // .Replace("-", "_"); - может пригодиться здесь

public class DataStruct
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_long { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> name_lang { get; set; }
    public string data_type { get; set; }
    public string cur_byte { get; set; }
    public string[] test { get; set; }
    public List<DataValue> value { get; set; }

    public string Text
    {
        get => name_lang[_lang];
        set => name_lang[_lang] = value;
    }
}
```

Всё, теперь можете спокойно вязать вторую колонку к свойству `Text`.

---

По поводу вложенного свойства - [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35863096/12888024) есть решение.

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = Grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (column.DataPropertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        object data = Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        string[] properties = column.DataPropertyName.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length && data != null; i++)
            data = data.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i]).GetValue(data);
        Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = data;
    }
}
```

После чего можно бужет просто написать через точку, например для исходной структуры данных `DataPropertyName = "name_lang.ru_RU"`. Но метод со словарем и дополнительным свойством надежнее.

Comment: спасибо большое за примеры, но я так понимаю, что обе конструкции не дадут изменить содержимое. Как стоит поступать в этом случаи? Или возможно нужно плясать вокруг DataGridView1_CellEndEdit?

Comment: @pepelxl в перврм случае к геттеру легко добавить сеттер, 1 строчка кода. Странно, что вы этого не заметили.

Comment: можно пример сеттера, а то это моя первая программа на c#, туплю по страшному

Comment: @pepelxl поправил код в ответе